# How can I control firework igniters (e-matches) with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, circuit-design, relay

I'm looking to do an arduino based firework show and am wondering how I can find out the specifications of e-matches, and what i'd need to use to control them?

Thanks

Comment: You contact the manufacturer, directly, like I did and speak with their engineers. You should ask for their "all fire" specification, which is whatever is required to guarantee firing one of them. Effectively, this is an action integral and they should be willing to share. Also, very carefully consider your safety protocols.

Answer (score 1):

A more powerful battery is surely not enough. An Arduino can supply only tens of milliamps where an e-match might draw a few amps. Just drive an [Arduino relay module](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino%20relais%20module&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjlgtqx77f3AhWQNOwKHUT1AdYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=arduino%20relais%20module&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAoQGDoHCCMQ7wMQJzoECAAQHlC2CljCEWCQEmgAcAB4AIABKogBnwKSAQE3mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=tx1rYqXLM5DpsAfE6oewDQ&bih=1057&biw=1920) and let the output of the relay switch the battery to the e-match. See [this sample](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/controling-5v-relay-with-wemos-d1-r1/671433). Just replace the lamp with the e-match.

Don't forget the mandatory extra manual switch between the battery and the e-match. You can never know if a glitch causes an Arduino to trigger the relay!

Comment: The wiring would be like in the sample with the light, but with an E-match instead of the light. All relays in the arduino relay modules will be fine. About 10Amps is probably fine

Comment: I don't know what level of synchronization is required for a fireworks show, but are you sure using relay modules could achieve it?

Comment: Lookup the datasheet of the used relay. I don't know if the delay (typical milliseconds) is acceptable to user270727

Answer (score 0):

What level of safety do you require?

In general, you can easily fire Pyro / Fireworks igniters using MOSFETs.  You should provide a decent bulk storage capacitor to provide the energy required.

You **can** fire most e-matches from a single-cell Li-Ion battery but you are right on the thin edge of it not being reliable.  Adding the bulk storage capacitor helps but higher voltage is really beneficial.  One product that we manufacture uses a DC-DC converter to charge a largish capacitor to about 14 Vdc.  That has been 100% reliable for more thousands of shots than I can count.

As one other person has commented: you really do need to consider the safety aspects of what you are doing.  A two-level interlock is always a good idea and is often mandated by regulation.

For us: the two level interlock is controlling the DC-DC converter (you can't fire the igniter if there isn't any charge in the capacitor) with the second level being the actual firing MOSFET.

Can you provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish?  Just modify your original question.